# How to define style using css for a range of class(.progress-10 to .progress-40)

Tags: css, sass

Edited: what i want is that from 10..30 to have a background and from 31..40 have another background

I just need to know how to define style in css for a range of classes for example if i have the following HTML:

```
<div class=progress-10></div>
<div class=progress-20></div>
<div class=progress-30></div>
<div class=progress-31></div>
<div class=progress-40></div>
```

is there a way to style all of them without adding them one by one in css as the below:

```
.progress-10,.progress-20,.progress-30 { background-color:red;}
```

is there's somthing like .progress-10..30 {...}??

Thanks

Comment: "*[What I] want is that from 10..30 to have a background and from 31...40 have another background...*" Would the background for the elements in the `10`-`30` range have the same colour? Or different colours?

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but you can use an selector like:

```
[class^="progress-"] {}
```

This will select all classes that *start* with your chosen string.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}

[class^="progress-"] {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-10"></div>
<div class="progress-20"></div>
<div class="progress-30"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that's would do the job and adding another class for all of them will do the same as well but what i wanted is that from 10..30 to have a background and from 31..40 have another background you get my point, i guess there's nothing in css like that i have to use javascript

Comment: While you said that this is not a perfect solution, it might be worth suggesting the use of custom `data-*` attributes (since this appears to represent some aspect of the element's state), in which case `[data-progress]` (as an example) would probably be more suited to the task. Failing that there's maybe `[class*="progress-"]`? @Ali: I'd suggest you update the question to clarify your requirements/intentions; because I would not have interpreted the question that way at all.